# match a pattern and print subsequent lines

Tags: sed, design-patterns, match

there are 200 files named File1_0.pdb,File1_60.pdb etc....it looks like:

```
ATOM      1  N   VAL     1       8.897 -21.545  -7.276  1.00  0.00
ATOM      2  H1  VAL     1       9.692 -22.015  -6.868  1.00  0.00
ATOM      3  H2  VAL     1       9.228 -20.766  -7.827  1.00  0.00
ATOM      4  H3  VAL     1       8.289 -22.236  -7.693  1.00  0.00
TER
ATOM      5  CA  VAL     1       8.124 -20.953  -6.203  1.00  0.00
ATOM      6  HA  VAL     1       8.072 -19.874  -6.345  1.00  0.00
ATOM      7  CB  VAL     1       6.693 -21.515  -6.176  1.00  0.00
ATOM      8  HB  VAL     1       6.522 -22.024  -5.227  1.00  0.00
ATOM      9  CG1 VAL     1       5.684 -20.370  -6.330  1.00  0.00
ATOM     10 1HG1 VAL     1       5.854 -19.861  -7.279  1.00  0.00
```

i have to extract the part after TER and put in a different file...this has to be done on all 200 files. I did something like  `sed '1,/TER/d' File1_0.pdb > 1_0.pdb`. But this will work for one file at a time...can there be a solution for all 200 files in one go... output file is named same only "File" is removed from the name...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in *.pdb; do sed '1,/TER/d' $i > ${i/File/}; done
```

Comment: +1. Better yet, `for i in {0..199} ; do sed '1,/TER/d' File1_$i.pdb > 1_$i.pdb ; done` -- which will allow this to be run multiple times and tweaked if necessary. (Using `*.pdb` would wrongly catch the output-files of previous runs.)

Comment: replace the "*.pdb" to "File*.pdb", and problem is solved. I assumed, the "200 file" is just a cca example, not an exact number in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
seq 0 200| xargs -i -n1 cp File1_{}.pdb 1_{}.pbd # backup files   
sed -si '1,/TER/d' 1_{0..200}.pdb                # edit files separately inline
```